# ZwReadVirtualMemory and PatchGuard

Tags: windows-7, driver

I have a question about calling the routine ZwReadVirtualMemory from my driver. I noticed it is not exported by ntokskrnl after dumping the EAT. How and where can I find the virtual address for this routine?

Is it located in the ssdt? if so, does not patchguard prevent me from reading there anyway? Or is that only for writing.

Also, this is for windows 7 x64.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing by ntdll trick you mean using that unsigned integer that is moved into the eax/rax register in usermode prior to making the actual syscall?

Answer (score 1):

`ZwReadVirtualMemory` is not exported from kernel. But you can find it in `SSDT`. Use ntdll trick. Don't worry about PatchGuard. It prevents only from code modification, reading is ok.

Also take into consideration that `ZwReadVirtualMemory` is not the only way to read virtual memory.

Comment: Neat. What are some other ways? Ive heard of KeStackAttachProcess. Anything else? Also it seems the ssdt export is missing in my ntoskrnl.exe here on x64 winodws 7. No idea why..

Comment: Yes, using KeStackAttachProcess. Maybe you are looking at the wrong index in SSDT?

Comment: Can you give more details about the "ntdll trick" in order to use ZwReadVirtualMemory? Thanks.

Comment: Map or read `ntdll.dll`, parse its headers and find NtReadVirtualMemory address, look at the beginning of the function, there should be `mov eax, index` instruction, grab the index from it. I hope you've got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that SSDT on win 64 doesn't hold pointers to functions. It holds offsets which are relative to the start of nt!KiServiceTable. Also one of the viable ways of finding SSDT is to perform some sort of pattern scan in order to locate. Basically for 64 bits just forget with tinkering freely with the SSDT. For more information read [this](http://www.kernelmode.info/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1146)

Furthermore - patchguard is just for modification of system-critical components.